# mod_rewrite performing unexpectedly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't figure this one out no matter how many times I google it or think about it. I have a RewriteRule in my .htaccess file: `RewriteRule ^/download/([^/\.])/?$ /downloadfile.php?f=$1 [L]`

When I use this, my page loads fine, but going to the link `http://www.example.com/download/file.ext`, it pulls a 404 page. However, if I load the page, then change my RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^/download/([^/\])/?$ /downloadfile.php?f=$1 [L]` (noting the RegEx change), the link works exactly how I expect it to... Until I reload the page, which results in a 500 error because of a bad regex expression? (I checked my Apache error log, thats how I know it reads as a bad regex)

So, what can I do to make this work? I've tried `(.*)` and `([.*])` for regex as well, that didn't work either.. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite strips out the prefix (the leading slash) from the URI when you use it in an .htaccess file. Your regex needs to have it removed:

```
RewriteRule ^download/([^/\.]*)/?$ /downloadfile.php?f=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Cheers Jon, I didn't even see that. All works now, except for the fact that the regex is actually `([^/]*) For me, because I need it to contain a period. Aside from that, thankyou. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/?download/([^/]*) /downloadfile.php?f=$1 [L]
```

The leading slash is required in apache 1.x and stripped in version 2.x
You were also denying the dot character.